# NHibernate Profiler does not work in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, nhibernate, .net-core-3.1, nhibernate-profiler

I'm trying to use NHibernate Profiler in a .NET Core 3.1 MVC app and although I've tried installing what the profiler insists it needs to be it's job (via nuget), I still cannot get NHibernate Profiler working with .NET Core 3.1.

I've started by adding a reference to `HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender` to the project and have tried invoking NHibernateProfile.Initialize() from Program.Main like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
...
}
```

As well as Startup's constructor

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
}
```

The first exception I received was:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I added that reference via nuget.

The next exception I received was:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.CodeDom, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I added the reference via nuget.

The last exception I received was the ultra-vague:

`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

NHibernate Profiler claims it works on .NET Core for the version 5.0 (I'm running build 5044) here:
http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf
[image]

but I can't get it to work.

I haven't tried running it in the mode where [you don't have to change application code](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/Products/nhprof/learn#ProfileAppWithConfiguration), but I don't see what the point is of going through all the rigmarole of log4net when I CAN change my app code (and the docs suggest you use the the .Initialize() call anyhow)

I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly and/or missing something. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using ? 5.2.6 ?

Comment: I solved the problem. The answer is below. Stackoverflow will not let me mark my own answer as the accepted answer for another 22 hours.

Answer (score 3):

So I was right, I was doing something incorrectly.

I was foolishly copying HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll into the .net core project instead of using nuget to get the NHibernateProfiler package and pull in the otehr needed dependencies and specific versions for me!

I went and grabbed this package/version via nuget:
[image]

and everything works.

Comment: This approach worked for me also. Unfortunately, their "How to use.txt" file included in the download from their website includes the following instructions for "Preparing an application to be profiled": Add a reference to HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll assembly (located in the Appender folder of the downloadable zip). That approach doesn't work in .NET Core 3.1.